# PHP Routing: Giving predefined routes higher priority

Tags: php, regex, url, routes

I'm creating a PHP application that makes routing URLs much easier.

```
    // Define the routes
    $routes = [
        '/programs',
        '/programs/{}',
        '/programs/{}/members',
        '/programs/{}/{}',
        '/programs/{}/{}/members'
    ];

    // Example URL
    $url = '/programs/test/members';

    /*
     * Split the URL at /
     * Remove the first and last value from the returned array
    */
    $parts = array_values( array_filter( preg_split( "/\//", $url ) ) );

    // Loop over the defined routes
    foreach($routes as $route){
        // Split the route into parts, like we do with the url
        $route_parts = array_values( array_filter( preg_split( "/\//", $route ) ) );

        /*
         * If the route parts is more than the parts of the url
         * then continue to the next value in the routes array
         */
        if( sizeof( $route_parts ) != sizeof( $parts ) ) continue;

        // Loop over the route parts
        for( $i=0; $i<sizeof( $route_parts ); $i++ ) {
            /*
             * Compare the route part to the url part and see if they match
             * or if the route part is {}
             */
            if ( $route_parts[ $i ] != '{}' && $route_parts[ $i ] != $parts[ $i ] ) continue;
        }

        // Echo the route if it passes all the above checks
        echo 'got through: '. $route . '<br />';
    }
```

This, in general sense, is working. However, as expected the code get's in a bit of a twist when it tries to get the route for the url specified. It returns both the

> /programs/{}/members

and

> /programs/{}/{}

routes - as they both match the URL.

I'm looking for pointers on how to put in some code so that the system knows that /programs/{}/members is a predefined route and should take higher priority than the /programs/{}/{} route - as the code should only ever return one route.

Thanks.

Comment: In your `$routes` table you list `/programs/{}/members` before `/programs/{}/{}` because it has a higher priority so the first route that gets matched is the "winner." Or it's the match with the fewest wildcards (i.e. `{}`) required for matching).

Comment: @Booboo Yeah, I had code to find the one with the fewest wildcards but I thought it was slightly inefficient as it was a seperate for loop over a separate array with the results from this function. I suppose the first solution could work, but say if it was users setting this up it could be easily breakable. Thanks for the suggestions though - really appreciated.

Comment: You can also always take the longest string :)

Answer (score 0):

With the assistance of @Booboo and @freeek I've come up with the answer below:

```
    // Define the routes
    $routes = [
        '/programs',
        '/programs/{}',
        '/programs/{}/{}',
    ];

    // Example URL
    $url = '/programs/some_program/some_course';

    /*
     * Split the URL at /
     * Remove the first and last value from the returned array
    */
    $parts = array_values( array_filter( preg_split( "/\//", $url ) ) );


    // Define valid routes array
    $valid_routes = $routes;

    // Loop over the defined routes
    foreach($routes as $route){
        // Split the route into parts, like we do with the url
        $route_parts = array_values( array_filter( preg_split( "/\//", $route ) ) );

        /*
         * If the route parts is more than the parts of the url
         * then continue to the next value in the routes array
         */
        if( sizeof( $route_parts ) != sizeof( $parts ) ){
            // Remove the route from the valid routes array
            $valid_routes = array_values( array_diff( $valid_routes, [$route] ) );
        }

        // Loop over the route parts
        for( $i=0; $i<sizeof( $route_parts ); $i++ ) {
            /*
             * Compare the route part to the url part and see if they match
             * or if the route part is {}
             */
            if ( $i >= sizeof( $parts ) || ( $route_parts[ $i ] != '{}' & $route_parts[ $i ] != $parts[ $i ] ) ){
                // Remove the route from the valid routes array
                $valid_routes = array_values( array_diff( $valid_routes, [$route] ) );
            }
        }
    }

    // Find the route with the least occurrence of the {} characters
    $route = $this->leastOccurrence( $valid_routes, '{}' );

    if( $route != null ){
        // Route found, output the route
        echo 'Found route: ' . $route;
    } else {
        // No route found, 404
        echo '404, not found';
    } 

    function leastOccurrence( $array, $characters ){
        if( sizeof( $array ) < 1 ) return null;
        $least = $array[0];
        foreach( $array as $item ){
            if( substr_count( $item, $characters ) < substr_count( $least, $characters ) ) $least = $item;
        }
        return $least;
    }
```